# How to get 2 parameter in href - Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Jsp code get from a row in table.

```
<li>
    <a href="otherpageJsp?idParam1=${value1}&idParam2=${value2}"
          onclick="otherpageJsp">Somelinktext</a>
</li>
```

in model and view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "otherpageJsp")
public ModelAndView goPage(@RequestParam String idParam1,String idParam2, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("otherpageJsp");
    mav.addObject("current", "otherpageJsp");
    mav.addObject("value1", idParam1);
    mav.addObject("value2", idParam2);
    return mav
```

when `onclick()` called, I only get value1, value2= null. Anyone can help me fix it?

Comment: Add `@RequestParam` to the `String idParam2` as well

Comment: your mean: @RequestParam String idParam2.

Comment: yes..did u try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `@RequestParam` to get the parameter value set to the method's parameter.

```
public ModelAndView goPage(@RequestParam String idParam1,@RequestParam String idParam2, Model model) {
```

Comment: I have other problem. If idParam1=${value1}&idParam2${value1}=${value2} so how can I set param for param 2

Comment: I didn't get ur question.plz explain a little.

Comment: <li><a href="otherpageJsp?idParam1=${value1}&idParam2${value1}=${value2}"</a></li>
I mean Id: param2 alway change follow value param1.

Comment: Sorry..I donot know about the dynamic parameter...Have to do research for myself too..

Comment: For <a href="otherpageJsp?idParam1=${value1}&idParam2${value1}=${value2}"</a>, append the value of idparam2 with value1 in controller and pass it. So in controller, write: mav.addObject("value2", idParam2 + idparam1); This will append the value of Id based on value1  @Scribbler

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `QueryParam` as you are sending the parameters in URL query string. Try this:

```
public ModelAndView goPage(@QueryParam("idParam1") String idParam1, @QueryParam("idParam2") String idParam2, Model model) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "otherpageJsp", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goPage(@RequestParam("idParam1") String idParam1, @RequestParam("idParam2") String idParam2, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("otherpageJsp");
    mav.addObject("current", "otherpageJsp");
    mav.addObject("value1", idParam1);
    mav.addObject("value2", idParam2);
    return mav
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I use jst, for the href

Html

```html
<c:url var="addNewDistribution" value="/credit/showFormforAddDistribution">
    <c:param name="credit"  value="${creditNumber}" />
    <c:param name="work"    value="${creditNumber}" />
</c:url>                    
<a href="${addNewDistribution}">add</a>
```

Model view

```
@GetMapping("/showFormforAddDistribution")
public String showFormforAddDistribution(@RequestParam String credit,@RequestParam String work, Model theModel) {}
```